# How to install openssl 1.0.2 with default openssl (1.1.1) on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: openssl

P4Python does not work on Ubuntu 16.04 since the distribution comes with **OpenSSL 1.1.0g**.([details](https://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/5457-will-p4python-be-updated-to-support-openssl-11x/)). I am trying to build P4Python from source using `--ssl path/to/openssl1.0`. I need to install **OpenSSL 1.0.2** along with the default version of OpenSSL. (Not sure if something would break if I downgrade OpenSSL). How do I install the older version of OpenSSL so that I can just use it for building P4Python?

Answer (score 9):

[This article](https://www.miguelvallejo.com/tag/installing-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu/) has a complete answer:

Reformatted slightly:

> cURL Method

```bash
# (Install cURL library)  
sudo apt-get install php5-curl 

# (Install compiling library Make)  
sudo apt-get install make 

# (single command that will download latest binaries, extract them, cd into the directory, compile configuration and then install the files)  
curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz | tar xz && cd openssl-1.0.2l && sudo ./config && sudo make && sudo make install 

# (This will create a sym link to the new binaries)  
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl` 

# (Used to check the version of the Current OpenSSL binaries)  
openssl version -v
```

> wget method

```bash
# (Install compiling library Make)  
sudo apt-get install make 

# (Download the latest OpenSSL 1.0.2g binaries)  
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz 

# (Extract the tar ball to the local directory)  
tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz 

# (Enter extracted OpenSSL directory)  
cd openssl-1.0.2l 

#  (Configure binaries for compiling)  
sudo ./config

# (install configured binaries)  
sudo make install 

# (This will create a sym link to the new binaries)  
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl` 

# (Used to check the version of the Current OpenSSL binaries)  
openssl version -v
```

Comment: Followed these instructions but at the end I get "Command 'openssl' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install openssl"

Comment: how do you revert these changes?

Comment: tried wget method. but `bash: /usr/bin/openssl: No such file or directory`

Comment: Command 'openssl' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install openssl

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades openssl1.0=1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.1 
echo "export OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/lib/ssl1.0/" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: It is not safe to downgrade OpenSSL to a 1.0.x version because many things will fail to build or operate properly.  If you need a different OpenSSL, I would suggest that you use a VM or container of the older Ubuntu with the older OpenSSL to do this, rather than downgrade your OpenSSL in this manner.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package openssl1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'openssl1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'openssl1.0'