# Have two different OpenSSL versions installed for rbenv - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssl, ruby, openssl

I want to have two different OpenSSL versions in my OS.
Right now, `openssl version -v` returns

> OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

I want to have OpenSSL 1.0.2 as well, for I need to install **Ruby 2.2.10** with **rbenv**, and for versions under 2.4 it requires an OpenSSL downgrade.

[How to install openssl 1.0.2 with default openssl (1.1.1) on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000629/how-to-install-openssl-1-0-2-with-default-openssl-1-1-1-on-ubuntu-16-04) - I've followed *monaye*'s answer in this thread, and managed to have OpenSSL installed: `openssl version -v`

> OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017

but having the OS use OpenSSL might conflict my Ruby 3.0.0 app, because I need to have both ssl versions available. This is why I have updated OpenSSL back to its latest version

*rbenv*'s docs have a [solution for this conflict in MacOS:](http://#%20with%20Homebrew%20on%20macOS%20brew%20install%20rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0%20RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=%22--with-openssl-dir=$(brew%20--prefix%20openssl@1.0)%22%20rbenv%20install%202.3.8)

> ## with Homebrew on macOS
>
> brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
> RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)" rbenv install 2.3.8

and I would need something similar in Ubuntu 20.04 - is it possible?

In the rbenv forums, below [OpenSSL version compatibility](http://RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=%22--with-openssl-dir=$(brew%20--prefix%20openssl@1.0)%22%20rbenv%20install%202.3.8) it says:

> When building Ruby 2.3 or older, you must ensure that OpenSSL 1.0 is available somewhere on the system and point to it via the --with-openssl-dir configure flag. At the moment, most Linux distributions that come with OpenSSL 1.1 have a separate package for OpenSSL 1.0.

But

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)" rbenv install 2.3.8
```

Fails: `Command 'brew' not found`

Comment: So ... where is brew installed? Either you have it not installed or it is not in the PATH and that would require you to add an absolute path.

Comment: Sorry, im new to Linux. I don't have brew, and I thought it was a MacOS package. ´sudo apt install brew´ returns ´unable to locate package brew´ and ´brew´ returns similar package names: qbrew and brec.

I am now trying to install brew

Comment: It is probably called linuxbrew ;-) Oh and a small note: you are probably better off installing Ubuntu in virtualbox and use the older ssl in there and not have 2 versions installed on 1 system.

Comment: it failed after installing brew and openssl. BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20210309)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20210322123729.48434.WmdkHX
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20210322123729.48434.log

Comment: this is the log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPDsWTgJ-bfh7G3iX64jGIY1iIK4fp-d/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://gist.github.com/souzagab/0ae60e61939d51385de87904b65b2da2) was the solution I found, and with a small tweak it worked.
Thanks to EliKazap
Edit /`etc/apt/sources.list` and add this at the end of the file: `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main`

then

```
Run sudo apt-get update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev

Run sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

check if the version is correct with `./usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl version`

and then

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/ssl/bin'" rbenv install 2.2.10
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard `--with-openssl-dir` solution works great if you compiled openssl in a standard way, but in some linux distros they have multiple versions of openssl that have been compiled in non-standard ways. For example, EPEL provides openssl11 on RHEL/CentOS 7. I was able to compile against it using:

```sh
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS='--with-openssl-dir=/usr/include/openssl11 --with-openssl-lib=/usr/lib64/openssl11 --with-openssl-include=/usr/include/openssl11' rbenv install 3.2.2
```