# Install Openssl v1.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: openssl

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and I installed the OpenSSL dev libraries to compile a project. This gave me OpenSSL version 1.1.x. However, it turns I need an older version of OpenSSL to compile the project:

https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/pull/13

How do I undo this version and reinstall an older version of OpenSSL? I think I require version 1.0.2.

(In general it would be useful how best to manage multiple versions on the same machine)

**UPDATE**

Tried the answer here:

[How to install openssl 1.0.2 with default openssl (1.1.1) on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000629/how-to-install-openssl-1-0-2-with-default-openssl-1-1-1-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But at the end, when checking the version I get:

```
openssl version -v 
Command 'openssl' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install openssl
```

Comment: In the answer you linked to, did you follow all the steps and compile the new binary from source? You're basically replacing the old (newer version) with the new (older version) so you either need the old version installed or symlink your new binary to `/usr/bin/openssl` and see if that works

Comment: @ElefantPhace yes, i followed the "wget" version