# Trying to install & Compile OpenSSL 1.1.1q

Tags: openssl

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm trying to downgrade and compile OpenSSL 1.1.1q but it don't seem to work. I've followed this guide and changed it to 1.1.1q

[How to install openssl 1.0.2 with default openssl (1.1.1) on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000629/how-to-install-openssl-1-0-2-with-default-openssl-1-1-1-on-ubuntu-16-04?newreg=64e23c35a5414ace8de5344d5303a072)

I use this

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz
tar -xzvf openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1q
sudo ./config
sudo make install
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl`
openssl version -v
```

But when I type

`openssl version -v`

I recieve

`-bash: /usr/bin/openssl: No such file or directory`

**whereis openssl** throws me

```
openssl: /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Comment: So run `/usr/local/bin/openssl version -v`

Comment: That gives me: -bash: /usr/local/bin/openssl: No such file or directory

Comment: `hash -r` rehashes the `PATH` for bash and should rid you of the first issue (no `/usr/bin/openssl`), and possibly the second. If `/usr/local/bin/openssl version -v`, as suggested by @Pilot6, really does not work, then recheck whether your `make install` actually worked. Finally, take heed of the warnings in the instructions you're linking to: downgrading OpenSSL may not be the wisest thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl`
```

The path is wrong, it should be as below (verified with openssl-1.1.1v):

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/openssl `which openssl`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "ldconfig" to configure the dynamic linker run-time bindings. Its primary purpose is to update the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified in the /etc/ld.so.conf file and the trusted directories. You will need sudo permission to run it:

```
sudo ldconfig
```